# Wireless issues in Fedora 25

Tags: networking, fedora, wifi, gnome

I am having difficulty with my Fedora 25 installation. I have been using the default gnome for a while, but wanted to try a different desktop environment. I installed Enlightenment using `dnf install enlightenment connman`. This worked, and enlightenment worked but the networking didn't. I wasn't as enamored with enlightenment as I thought I would be so I booted back into gnome and deleted enlightenment but I also had networking issues in gnome. The little wifi icon now had a question mark. It says it's connected to my network when click on it, and I can also connect to `192.168.1.1` but I can't actually get to the Internet. The `NetworkManager` service is enabled and running `rfkill` shows nothing is blocked and `nmcli` shows me connected to my home network. But every time I open a browser i can't get to any websites and I can't `ping` any websites either. I have no idea why I can't get to the network even though it was working right before i installed Enlightenment. I have found almost no information on the Internet and have no idea what the actual problem is, since as far as all of the networking information shows I am connected to the my home network. I have tried rebooting, logging out and back in, powering down completely, etc. If I can't resolve this I think I'm just going to switch to the KDE variant of Fedora, although I would really rather not since I have a ton of config files and such installed and configured just the way I like.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and with further investigation found that I could ping to IP addresses (ping XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) both on my local LAN and on the internet (ping 8.8.8.8). Pinging to web addresses did not work, such as ping mail.yahoo.com, indicating a problem with domain name resolution.  When the uninstall of connman takes place it leaves behind symbolic links for the /etc/resolv.conf file to /var/run/connman/resolv.conf.  This link needs to be replaced with the link back to the NetworkManager config files, which are in /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf.  The command is;

ln -sf /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

Once the link back to the NetworkManager file is established connections using domain names can again be established.